# Grammar proper usage of tenses

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

I arrived at the station at the last minute before the bus left?

I feel as if this question is wrong as far as the tenses are concerned but I'm quite confused.any thoughts?

Comment: The juxtaposition of the two temporal adverbials is jarring and probably ungrammatical. 'I arrived at the station at the last minute' and 'I arrived at the station before the bus left' are of course fine. 'I arrived at the station a minute before the bus left/was due to leave' include all the information. Tenses etc are fine with these, in spite of the former using two past tenses for sequential events (no past perfect is required as 'before' orders events).

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

Comment: There is nothing ungrammatical about it in the sense of it following the normal rules of syntax. But it is a little unusual.

Comment: Very kind of you to help me :)thanks